# Time complexity of dijkstra using Fibonacci min heap

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have been trying to optimize my Dijkstra algorithm using Fibonacci min-heap which according to this *[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)[article] should take complexity $O(M+N*log(N))$ where:

- M is the number of edges
- N is the number of vertices

I've computed the overall complexity but I'm not sure if it's correct and I would love to get some suggestions:

First and foremost we have the "declarations & assignments" which I'll try to avoid since they're all constant elementary operations which take $O(1)$ and have no contribution to my complexity as n $\to$ $\infty$.

First for-loop which takes complexity $O(N)$.

The headpop method that takes $O(log(N))$ assuming that we look up for the node with smallest weight in a binary heap.

Here is where I m not certain. So we take the node with small weight from the source and then update the labels of the neighbours, which means we go to the adjacency list ( in this case dictionary ) and check all possible edges in the set $\delta^+(v)$, i.e. all nodes going from v to another vertex u out of the set $\S$ containing the nodes already visited. So overall complexity $O(n-1)$ for complete graphs.

Having all these in mind I ended up with: $O(N\cdot(log(N) + M))$ $\equiv$ $O(N\cdot(log(N) + N - 1))$ $\equiv$ $O(N \cdot log(N) + N^2)$ $\equiv$ $O(N^2)$ for large values of N.

This is not the expected output that I wanted from my solution, hence I'd be glad to hear your suggestion.

```
def dijkstra2(successors, s):

    S = []; S.append(s)
    n = len(successors)
    L = dict(); L[s] = 0
    P = dict(); P[s] = '-'

    # Iterate through the V/{s}-nodes and set L[j] to infinity and P[j] to s.
    for o in range(0, n):
        if o != s:
            L[o] = numpy.inf
            P[o] = s

    # Visited vector.
    visited = [False] * n;

    # Heapq
    queue = [(0, s)];


    while queue:
        par_len, v = heappop(queue);
        # v is unvisited
        if visited[v] is False:
            visited[v] = True
            for w, edge_len in successors[v].items():
                # Check if the child is unvisited and compute the distance.
                if visited[w] is False and edge_len + par_len < L[w] :
                    heappush(queue, (edge_len + par_len, w))
                    L[w] = edge_len + par_len
                    P[w] = v

    return L, P
```

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm is:

```
O(|E| |decrease-key(Q)| + |V| |extract-min(Q)|)
```

Fibonacci heap:

```
O(|E| + |V| log |V|)
```

binary heap:

```
O((|E| + |V|) log |V|)
```

E is:

```
|E| = O(|V|^2)
```

Q is:
The min-priority queue ordering vertices by their own current distance estimate.

Initialize heaps:

```
from heapq import *
from random import randint

f = FibonacciHeap()
h = []
n = 100
for i in xrange(0, n):
    r = randint(1, 1000)
    f.insert(r)
    heappush(h, r)
```

Code for print running time:

```
import time
# test fib heap running time 
start_time = time.time()
while f.total_nodes > 0:
    m = f.extract_min()
print "%s seconds run time for fib heap" % (time.time() - start_time)

# test heapq running time 
start_time = time.time()
while h:
    m = heappop(h)
print "%s seconds run time for heapq" % (time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: I m sorry, but what's the overall complexity and is my approach valid or?

Comment: @user181475 I updated my answer, please accept it if it helps.

Comment: @user181475 You can also visit it http://www.kr.tuwien.ac.at/events/wlp06/02-final.pdf

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but please let me know how to use that piece of code to compute the complexity of my method. I m not interested to see the complexity of Fib min-heap. My question is if my approach is valid

Comment: I don't have enough reputation cause' I would have given you a +1 for the answer

Comment: @user181475 no matter, I am happy that your problem is solved.